# Angular Object Binding

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I don't have too much experience with angular but there is a task that I have to handle in my job. Basically, I have a form where users can insert values and these values directly go to the backend for processing.
On the form we are submitting a PolicyDocument which has these parameters:

```
import {ContactFrequency} from './ContactFrequency';

export class PolicyDocument {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    file: string;
    validFrom: string;
    country: string;
    majorVersion: number;
    minorVersion: number;
    status: string;// TODO dmann make enum or string set
    primaryText: string;
    secondaryText: string;
    textBlocks: TextBlock[];
    contactFrequency?: ContactFrequency;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

And the ContactFrequency is like this:

```
export class ContactFrequency{
    id:number;
    contactFrequency: number;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

And the form that we are taking values:

```
            <label for="inputContactFrequency" class="col-1 col-form-label">Contact Frequency (Days)</label>
            <div class="col-2 pr-0">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputContactFrequency" placeholder="(Optional)"
                       [ngModel]="detail?.contactFrequency?.contactFrequency"
                       name="contactFrequency.contactFrequency" [disabled]="fieldsDisabled()" min="0"/>
            </div>
```

Sorry for the messy naming convention. My problem is; whenever i insert a value, the payload that goes to back-end is like below.

```
contactFrequency: 180
```

If i dont insert a value it is:

```
contactFrequency:{
   contactFrequency: null
}
```

The payload that goes when I am not inserting a value is ok, it works as I expect but whenever I insert a value it doesn't go as an object. Is there a quick/easy way to modify it as passes object to backend?

When the form filled and submitted, first handleCreate method being activated:

```
    handleCreate(policyDocument: PolicyDocument) {
        this.userFeedbackService.clearAllUserFeedback();
        if (this.validatePolicyDocumentDate(policyDocument)) {
            this.policyDocumentService.create(policyDocument).subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    console.log('handleCreate returned ', response);
                    this.router.navigate(['/policies'])
                        .then(() => this.userFeedbackService.clearAndAddSuccess('Policy created successfully'));
                },
                () => {
                    this.removeDefaultValidityInDays();
                    window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
                });
        } else {
            window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
    }
```

And then it goes to service:

```
create(policyDocument: PolicyDocument): Observable<PolicyDocument> {
        console.log("Policy Document for frequency rule: " + policyDocument);
        console.log("Contact Frequency for frequency rule: " + policyDocument.contactFrequency?.contactFrequency);
        return this.http
            .put(POLICY_DOCUMENTS_API, policyDocument)
            .map(data => {
                this.userFeedbackService.clearAndAddSuccess('Policy document has been created successfully');
                return <PolicyDocument>data;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.userFeedbackService.addError('Failed creating policyDocument');
                throw new Error(err.toString());
            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how is it being sent to the back-end.?

Comment: Hi @SatsangpriyadasSwami, I just added it to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see the next request when is null is ok because this property is typed by `ContactFrequency` model:

```
contactFrequency:{
   contactFrequency: null
}
```

... So, when you are typing something the input is responding as number atribute. Is fine!, the problem here is that you need catch the request before the http request is executed, in that moment you need create the object as `contactFrequency`:

May you have service like this:

```
save(data: YourModel): Observable<YourModel> {

    return this.http.post(url, data).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        ... code
      })
    );
  }
```

You need to call `serivce.save(data)` in your controller, and here you need to buid the object like this:

```
const obj: PolicyDocument = {
    bla: 'bla',
    ble: 'ble',
    contactFrequency: {
        id: 'xyz',
        contactFrequency: 180
    }
    
}
```

You have the value 180, then build the object, then call `service.save(data)`

My recomendation is to use `reactive forms`, because you can subscribe to the input and buid the value of `contactFrequency` model

In my opinion `template forms` must be deprecated.